# Seiyria/bootstrap slider moving back to start when max,min value changes

Tags: angular, bootstrap-slider

I am having an issue with the bootstrap slider. I have  three sliders which work together. The first and third sliders are used to calculate a value for the second slider. The min,max values of the second slider are determined through the first and third slider.

My problem is, if I have the second slider dragged all the way (i.e, 15) to the max value and the max value changes (i.e from 15 to 18) by dragging the sliders of the first or third slider, the second slider goes back to its starting position instead of staying on the previous max value (15) and letting me drag it to the new max value (18).

The value does sticks (i.e 15) but the slider it self just shifts back to the start.

Here is the slider code. I am using the Angular version of it.

```
  <div class="col-md-4 slider-col">
<label [translate]="'LABEL_TEXT.DOWN_PAYMENT'"></label>
<div class="value">${{ downPayment || 0 | number: "1.0-0" }}</div>
<div class="mv-slider">
<mv-slider
  [(value)]="downPayment"
  [min]="product.downPayment.min"
  [max]="product.downPayment.max"
  enabled="true"
  step="100"
  refresh="{ useCurrentValue: false }"
  (slideStop)="getPricingDetail()"
></mv-slider>
```

Comment: Since you're using the angular version, it'd help if you could provide a stackblitz or similar with what your problem is.

Comment: I have been asked to debug a website which has a lot of components, am not sure how much should I stackblitz to help solve my, also, the website's source code is confidential which is another issue.

Comment: From what I have tested so far, the slider moves back to the start when the max value changes. It then lets me drag the slider all the way to the new max value. Its just not sticking to the previous max value and allowing me to drag it further more to the new max value

Comment: if you can't create a MVCE, then you can't expect people to be able to help you very effectively.